# Eclipse Software Updates unable to satisfy dependency

Tags: eclipse

Recently, my Eclipse 3.4 installation started complaining while trying to update installed software.

I normally have Automatic Updates switched on, so this is particularly annoying.

Updates are found, but I am unable to install them because eclipse is unable to satisfy version dependencies.

From the .log file:

!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director 2 0 2008-11-17 16:07:58.006
!MESSAGE Problems resolving provisioning plan.
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director 2 0 2008-11-17 16:07:58.006
!MESSAGE Unable to satisfy dependency from org.eclipse.jst.web_ui.feature.feature.group 3.1.0.v200809240655-7E6EAaDgvY1exFj6Cn354dmz01jf to requiredCapability: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu/org.eclipse.wst.web_ui.feature.feature.group/[3.1.0,4.0.0).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director 2 0 2008-11-17 16:07:58.006
!MESSAGE Unable to satisfy dependency from org.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.data.core 1.0.0.200612181 to requiredCapability: osgi.bundle/com.ibm.icu/[3.4.4,3.5.0).

Now, I haven't changed my selection of features - it is just trying to update existing ones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the new version of jst, which has been released to the jst update site, relies on a new version of wst.

The update site for wst is not the same as for jst, and hadn't been updated on the 17th.

Writing today, on the 19th, the jst update site now has the correct new version, and the update will go through without problems.

Answer (score 1):

It seems it is a current [problem](https://glassfishplugins.dev.java.net/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=54), where the Eclipse p2 update process does not warn the user of missing dependencies and happily tries to install a new server plugin, then fails on restart and leaves the user out of luck.

An [Eclipse bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=246208) is in progress...